# What are the default settings in debconf's configuration?

Tags: dpkg, debconf

I had to run `dpkg-reconfigure -a` for certain reasons, and consequently given options for configure `debconf`. But I don't really know how those change things, and want to use the default settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formulating Nimmermehr's answer into 2 commands that do the trick:

```
linenum=$(cat /var/cache/debconf/config.dat | grep -n 'Name: debconf/priority' | cut -d: -f1)
sed -n "$linenum,$(($linenum + 4))p" /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

Comment: Your answer should stand as it's own and not rely on another answer - so please explain what this accomplishes.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to open the `debconf` template database `/var/cache/debconf/templates.dat` with your favourite text editor and search for the entries of the package `debconf` (`debconf/frontend` and `debconf/priority`). The entries have the property `Default` which specifies the default value.